# Paragraph based searching using before and after conditions UNIX KSH

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file like:

```
<Set of long paragraphs here>
<Set of long paragraphs here>
<Set of long paragraphs here>
After
Address1
Address2
Address3
Before
<Set of long paragraphs here>
<Set of long paragraphs here>
<Set of long paragraphs here>
After
Address1
Address2
Address3
Before
<Set of long paragraphs here>
<Set of long paragraphs here>
<Set of long paragraphs here>
After
Address1
Address2
Address3
Before
<Set of long paragraphs here>
<Set of long paragraphs here>
<Set of long paragraphs here>
After
Address1
Address2
Address3
Before
<Set of long paragraphs here>
<Set of long paragraphs here>
<Set of long paragraphs here>
After
Address1
Address2
Address3
Before
<Set of long paragraphs here>
<Set of long paragraphs here>
<Set of long paragraphs here>
```

I need to write the lines between the words `After` and `Before` into separate output files. For example, the output files should look like:

```
Line Number : Address1
Line Number : Address2
Line Number : Address3
......................
......................
```

I tried this:

```
awk '/After/,/Before/' Details.txt>output.txt
```

but it didn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$ awk '/After/{a=1;next}/Before/{a=0}; (a==1){print NR" : "$0}' file 
5 : Address1
6 : Address2
7 : Address3
13 : Address1
14 : Address2
15 : Address3
21 : Address1
22 : Address2
23 : Address3
29 : Address1
30 : Address2
31 : Address3
37 : Address1
38 : Address2
39 : Address3
```

The idea is very simple. The `a` variable changes value if the current line matches `After` or `Before` and we print the line only if `a` is equal to 1.

To save them into separate output files, you could do:

```
awk '/After/{a=1; k++;next}/Before/{a=0}; (a==1){print NR" : "$0 > k".out"}' file
```

Here, I am using the variable `k` to count how many times the word `After` is found. The output file will be the current value of `k` and `.out`. If I run the above on your example, I get:

```
$ ls
1.out  2.out  3.out  4.out  5.out
```